# SQL claiming incorrect datetime value despite the row being timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The thing is that the column (start) is set to be timestamp.

So I wrote the following code for insert query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO {$this->table_name} (`user_id`, `name`, `code`, `start`, `city`, `state`, `groups`) VALUES ( :user_id, :name, :code, TIMESTAMP( :start ), :city, :state, :groups)";

        $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);

        $stmt->bindParam(":user_id", $this->user_id);
        $stmt->bindParam(":name", $this->name);
        $stmt->bindParam(":code", $this->code);
        $stmt->bindParam(":start", $this->start);
        $stmt->bindParam(":city", $this->city);
        $stmt->bindParam(":state", $this->state);
        $stmt->bindParam(":groups", $this->groups);



        if ($stmt->execute()) { ........
```

All of the variables, except for 'groups' are strings. 'groups' is a JSON.

The following error arise:

> "Incorrect datetime value: '597492800'"

So the question is why is it saying incorrect datetime, when the column is a timestamp and I am inserting the timestamp.

Even when I tried to set the timestamp to int, it did not solve the problem.

```
$stmt->bindParam(":start", $this->start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

I am sending the timestamp from backend and want to save that. I do not need any conversion to timestamp from some type of format as the timestamp has the proper format already.

I am kind of new to the sql world and this came as a surprise to me. I'd be super glad if you helped me as I've spent whole day working out just this one relatively easy insert.

(Mysql version : 8)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `PDO::PARAM_INT` would be the incorrect type - it should be `PDO::PARAM_STR`. What value are you supplying for `$this->start`?

Comment: change your column to an INT field or a TEXT field with roughly 20 characters, else you need to convert your date really to a unix timestamp

Comment: "Timestamp" is just a generic English word for date and time measurements. You're probably assuming it's a synonym for Unix time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`TIMESTAMP()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestamp) takes a `date` or `datetime` expression, and `597492800` is not such a value.  Something like `'2020-08-12'` would be.

The error seems pretty clear.

What is not clear is what you want to do -- because the question does not explain that.  I might speculate that you want [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) to convert a number to a date/time value.

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear. I just need to save the timestamp as it is (1234213421). There is no need for conversion as I send the timestamp from frontend, not any other time format. FROM_UNIXTIME() is what I probably needed. I just thought that FROM_UNIXTIME() is used for DATETIME column for conversion from timestamp. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.

Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html